# Проблема с вводом переменных Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Только начинаю изучать Python, однако возникла проблема с вводом переменных:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print(a + b)
```

При запуске программы и вводе переменных, например 1 и 2(ввожу через enter, не в одну строку) возникает данная ошибка, хотя на выходе ожидается 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "****", line 2, in <module>
b = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Вторая переменная, насколько я понял, просто не считывается. Причем возникает проблема только в том случае, если вводить переменные подряд. Если команды ввода разделить, то тогда они будут работать нормально. Вводим 1 и 2:

```
a = int(input())
print()
b = int(input())
print(a + b)
```

На выходе получаем 3, т е программа исправно работает.
Хотелось бы услышать, возможно ли вводить 2 переменные подряд именно таким способом, без использования различных костылей. Заранее спасибо.
P.S
Через отладчик программа работает исправно и никаких проблем не возникает.

Comment: Да, возможно "вводить 2 переменные подряд именно таким способом". Возьмите за правило: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: И вы просто лишний раз Enter нажимаете. Или клавиша залипает на клавиатуре. Вам это прямо в ошибке написано: `invalid literal [удалил]: ''`

Comment: Клавиша точно не залипает. Странно, что через отладчик программа работает исправно.

Comment: У вас совершенно точно дважды учитывается Enter. Поведение в IDLE и PyCharm у меня идентично - при двойном Enter выдаётся подобная ошибка, при нормальном вводе всё работает. Попробуйте перегрузить всё, включая ноутбук. И проверьте в IDLE на всякий случай.

Comment: Всесильная перезагрузка ноутбука не помогла. Скорее всего действительно что-то с enter-ом, однако как это исправить я не представляю. В любом случае спасибо.

Comment: проверьте, в документах при вводе Enter однократном что происходит? Один печатается или два? И проверьте в IDLE работу кода. Что-то может стать понятнее.

Comment: К сожалению проверить в IDLE сейчас нет возможности. Однако в облачной среде Google Colab все работает отлично. Еще раз проверил enter : нажимается только один раз. Скорее всего проблема связана с каким-либо сбоем или особенностью Pycharm.

Comment: На всякий случай: у меня PyCharm 2021.3.3 (Community Edition). Build #PC-213.7172.26, built on March 16, 2022.

Comment: Включите эмуляцию консоли. Это баг пайчарма. Уже обсуждалось здесь. Через поиск поищите. Буквально 1-2 дня назад. Я там и инструкцию оставлял как включить

Answer (score 0):

Вы вводите дробные числа или целые? Первый код должен работать при вводе переменных подряд. Если вы подаете туда дробные числа через точку, то попробуйте это:

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
print(a + b)
```

Comment: Пытался вводить и целые числа, и дробные, а также пробовал не присваивать переменной тип данных. Но второй переменной просто не присваивается какое-либо значение.

Comment: А как вы числа вводите? может у вас действительно проблемы с клавишей "Enter ". Алгоритм выполнения кода такой (если на кнопочном уровне): 1. Shift+Enter для запуска кода 2. Ввод первого числа в поле + Enter, 3. Ввод второго числа в поле + Enter. И вам выводится результат. А какой кстати программой вы пользуетесь?

Comment: Может вы вводите через какую нибудь виртуальную клавиатуру?

Comment: Это не ответ. Это набор предположений. Комментарий дан относительно применения правил форума.

Comment: Алгоритм ввода именно такой, какой вы писали. Проблема точно не в клавише, я проверил её работоспособность, даже использовал 2й enter на клавиатуре. Пользуюсь программой PyCharm.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить ваш код в облачной среде "Google Colab"

Comment: В Google Colab все отлично работает. Скорее всего это просто особенность Pycharm, какой-либо сбой или проблема с клавишей enter.

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо всем, кто помог с решением данного вопроса. Проблема была связана с двойным нажатием клавиши enter при вводе переменных и/или особенностью программы Pycharm, в которой и был написан код. Если у вас возникла такая же проблема, то её можно исправить добавлением любой команды между вводом переменных(например, "print()"), или же использовать методы ввода переменных в одну строку.

Answer (score 0):

Это баг текущей версии пайчарм. Обсуждалось здесь уже. Ищем через поиск как исправить